# Did "float: center" ever work in CSS?

Tags: css, css-float, legacy-code

I have seen "float: center;" in code I have inherited.

Was there ever a time (or place) that this did something? Or was the original the coder just wrong?

Comment: Yeah, that never existed. There is float : left || right || none || inherit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not property called center for float. It has only this property

1. **Float: None;** (The element is not floated, and will be displayed just where it occurs in the text)
2. **Float:left**(The element floats to the left)
3. **Float:right**(The element floats the right)
4. **Float:initial** (Sets this property to its default value)
5. **Float:inherit**(Inherits this property from its parent element)

Comment: Good to know. I have only been coding CSS for 2 years. I didn't think there had ever been a "center" option. It does make me wonder what the original coder was thinking?